# Javascript - Multiple of the same tab on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I roleplay on online forums. I'm trying to create a tabbed signature for my forum so that you can tab back and forth from one character on the account to another. The code works perfectly, the tabs both accurately show the information, and everything is great.

Until I post more than once a page on the forum. AKA, the tabs show up more than once on the page. Then, when I click the tab on *any* signature other than the first one, the picture disappears and the first signature is the only one that 'tabs.'

Is there a way to make JS work so that *whatever* tab I click, it will load on *that* signature, not just the first one on the page?

Note that I do NOT want to add more tabs (or change the tab ID) since this will be pulled from the same place each time.

I've attached my **code** below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
      var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

      $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
      $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

      $(this).addClass('current');
      $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
   });
});
```

```css
body{width: 630px; height: 300px;position:relative;margin:20px auto;}
   .container{width: 600px; height: 250px; background: none; position: relative; margin: 20px auto; overflow: hidden; --background:none; --bg1:#eee; --pax:#490f0e; --song:#5e9984; --aain:#722696; --lore:#000; --zyra:#c99416; --amber:#dba297;}
   ul.tabs{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;list-style: none;}
   ul.tabs li{position: relative; width: 25px; height: 14px; background: none; top:1px; left: 1px; display: inline-block; cursor:crosshair; z-index: 2; padding: 10px 5px; padding-right: 20px; font-family: Homemade Apple; font-size: 20px; font-style: none; color: #aaa; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px; margin-right: -2px; text-align: left; transition: 0.3s;}
   ul.tabs li.current{background: transparent;color: #222;}
   .tab-content{display: none; background: #eee; width:598px; height:230px; border: 1px solid #ddd;}
   .tab-content.current{display: inherit;}
   .bpyand { position: relative; width: 10px; height: 14px; background: none; top:1px; left: 10px; display: inline-block; cursor:crosshair; z-index: 2; padding: 15px 25px; font-family: Homemade Apple; font-size: 25px; font-style: none; color: #5e9984; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px; margin-right: -2px; text-align: right; }
   .charname {font-family: Homemade Apple; position: absolute; text-transform: lowercase; line-height: 105%; font-size: 40px; top: 95px; left: 40px; width: 0px; text-align:right; transition: 1s;}
   .charblock {background: transparent; position: absolute; height: 270px; width: 250px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; transition: 1s;}
   .charinfo {font-family: cabin; text-transform: uppercase; position: absolute; color: transparent; font-size: 10px; top: 130px; left: 40px; width: 200px; line-height: 100%; transition: 1s; text-align:right;}
   .charstats {width:300px; height: 240px; position: absolute; left: -300px; top: 70px; padding-right: 1px; font-family: cabin; color: #777; font-size: 11px; text-align: justify; line-height: 130%; overflow: auto; transition: 1s;}
   .charstats h1 {font-size: 15px; font-family:  Homemade Apple; text-transform: lowercase;}
   .charstats h1:before {display: inline-block; content: ""; background: #777; width: 0px; height: 15px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;}
   .charav {width: 300px; height: 230px; background-size: cover; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 44px; transition: 1s;}
   .tab-content:hover .charname {width:558px; color: #777; transition: 1.3s;}
   .tab-content:hover .charav { opacity: .2; }
   .tab-content:hover .charinfo {width:558px; color: #777; transition: 1.3s;}
   .tab-content:hover .charstats { left: 5px; }
   .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
   .tg td{border-color:transparent;font-size:14px; overflow:hidden;padding:5px 5px;word-break:normal;}
   .tg th{border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:5px 5px;word-break:normal;}
   .tg .tg-left{text-align:left;vertical-align:middle}
   .tg .tg-right{text-align:right;vertical-align:middle}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">paxton</li><div class="bpyand">&&</div>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">songurseinth</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
<div class="charname" style="color:var(--pax);">Paxton</div><div class="charblock"><div class="charinfo">liaison-turned-weyrling<br>23 turns, female<br>curious, charismatic<br>hardworking, professional</div></div><div class="charstats"><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Strength</h1></th><th class="tg-left">8</th><th class="tg-right">13</th><th class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Dexterity</h1></th></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Constitution</h1></td> <td class="tg-left">14</td><td class="tg-right">12</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Intelligence</h1></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Wisdom</h1></td><td class="tg-left">10</td><td class="tg-right">15</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Charisma</h1></td></tr></table></div><div class="charav" style="background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/67198afb06c5f06e21d99f13b8b80614/tumblr_pi3a8czLo71xfq869o1_500.gif)"></div>


    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
<div class="charname" style="color:var(--song);">Songurseinth</div><div class="charblock"><div class="charinfo">liaison-turned-weyrling<br>23 turns, female<br>curious, charismatic<br>hardworking, professional</div></div><div class="charstats"><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Strength</h1></th><th class="tg-left">8</th><th class="tg-right">13</th><th class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Dexterity</h1></th></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Constitution</h1></td> <td class="tg-left">14</td><td class="tg-right">12</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Intelligence</h1></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Wisdom</h1></td><td class="tg-left">10</td><td class="tg-right">15</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Charisma</h1></td></tr></table></div><div class="charav" style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/mNQ1bXs/bringmeasonghatch.png)"></div>
    </div></div>
```

A sample where I clicked the second table/tab, but the first one changed instead:
https://i.postimg.cc/hPM03TWv/example.png

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the event listeners you're using are attached to the first instance of your signature on the page.

The solution is to "scope" the event listeners so they only clear and set the "current" class within the signature that was interacted with.

## HTML Changes

I wrapped your whole signature up in a `.signature'` class div. This allows us to use JavaScript to add and scope event listeners on a per signature basis.

Because `id`s need to be unique on the page (and your signature can appear more than once) you need to refrain from using `id`s in your signature. I simply moved the `tab-1` `id` attribute into the `class` attribute on the same element.

So: `<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">` becomes `<div class="tab-content tab-1">`

## JS Changes

I rewrote your JS without jQuery. I've commented the code but in short it loops over each signature and adds click event handlers that are scoped to only modify the elements within that signature.

```js
// Select all signature elements and loop over them
var signatures = document.querySelectorAll('.signature').forEach(signature => {

  // Select and loop over each tab link within a signature
  signature.querySelectorAll('.tab-link').forEach(tabLink => {
  
    // Add a click event listener to the lab link
    tabLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
      // Clear current class from this signatures tab link and tab content
      signature.querySelectorAll('.tab-link, .tab-content').forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove('current')
      })

      // Add current class to the tab link and tab content that was clicked
      var tabSelector = tabLink.dataset.tab
      tabLink.classList.add('current');
      signature.querySelector('.' + tabSelector).classList.add('current')
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body{width: 630px; height: 300px;position:relative;margin:20px auto;}
   .container{width: 600px; height: 250px; background: none; position: relative; margin: 20px auto; overflow: hidden; --background:none; --bg1:#eee; --pax:#490f0e; --song:#5e9984; --aain:#722696; --lore:#000; --zyra:#c99416; --amber:#dba297;}
   ul.tabs{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;list-style: none;}
   ul.tabs li{position: relative; width: 25px; height: 14px; background: none; top:1px; left: 1px; display: inline-block; cursor:crosshair; z-index: 2; padding: 10px 5px; padding-right: 20px; font-family: Homemade Apple; font-size: 20px; font-style: none; color: #aaa; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px; margin-right: -2px; text-align: left; transition: 0.3s;}
   ul.tabs li.current{background: transparent;color: #222;}
   .tab-content{display: none; background: #eee; width:598px; height:230px; border: 1px solid #ddd;}
   .tab-content.current{display: inherit;}
   .bpyand { position: relative; width: 10px; height: 14px; background: none; top:1px; left: 10px; display: inline-block; cursor:crosshair; z-index: 2; padding: 15px 25px; font-family: Homemade Apple; font-size: 25px; font-style: none; color: #5e9984; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: -1px; margin-right: -2px; text-align: right; }
   .charname {font-family: Homemade Apple; position: absolute; text-transform: lowercase; line-height: 105%; font-size: 40px; top: 95px; left: 40px; width: 0px; text-align:right; transition: 1s;}
   .charblock {background: transparent; position: absolute; height: 270px; width: 250px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; transition: 1s;}
   .charinfo {font-family: cabin; text-transform: uppercase; position: absolute; color: transparent; font-size: 10px; top: 130px; left: 40px; width: 200px; line-height: 100%; transition: 1s; text-align:right;}
   .charstats {width:300px; height: 240px; position: absolute; left: -300px; top: 70px; padding-right: 1px; font-family: cabin; color: #777; font-size: 11px; text-align: justify; line-height: 130%; overflow: auto; transition: 1s;}
   .charstats h1 {font-size: 15px; font-family:  Homemade Apple; text-transform: lowercase;}
   .charstats h1:before {display: inline-block; content: ""; background: #777; width: 0px; height: 15px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;}
   .charav {width: 300px; height: 230px; background-size: cover; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 44px; transition: 1s;}
   .tab-content:hover .charname {width:558px; color: #777; transition: 1.3s;}
   .tab-content:hover .charav { opacity: .2; }
   .tab-content:hover .charinfo {width:558px; color: #777; transition: 1.3s;}
   .tab-content:hover .charstats { left: 5px; }
   .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
   .tg td{border-color:transparent;font-size:14px; overflow:hidden;padding:5px 5px;word-break:normal;}
   .tg th{border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:5px 5px;word-break:normal;}
   .tg .tg-left{text-align:left;vertical-align:middle}
   .tg .tg-right{text-align:right;vertical-align:middle}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Homemade+Apple&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="signature">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">paxton</li><div class="bpyand">&&</div>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">songurseinth</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content current tab-1">
      <div class="charname" style="color:var(--pax);">Paxton</div>
      <div class="charblock"><div class="charinfo">liaison-turned-weyrling<br>23 turns, female<br>curious, charismatic<br>hardworking, professional</div></div><div class="charstats"><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Strength</h1></th><th class="tg-left">8</th><th class="tg-right">13</th><th class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Dexterity</h1></th></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Constitution</h1></td> <td class="tg-left">14</td><td class="tg-right">12</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Intelligence</h1></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Wisdom</h1></td><td class="tg-left">10</td><td class="tg-right">15</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Charisma</h1></td></tr></table></div><div class="charav" style="background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/67198afb06c5f06e21d99f13b8b80614/tumblr_pi3a8czLo71xfq869o1_500.gif)">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content tab-2">
      <div class="charname" style="color:var(--song);">Songurseinth</div>
      <div class="charblock"><div class="charinfo">liaison-turned-weyrling<br>23 turns, female<br>curious, charismatic<br>hardworking, professional</div></div><div class="charstats"><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Strength</h1></th><th class="tg-left">8</th><th class="tg-right">13</th><th class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Dexterity</h1></th></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Constitution</h1></td> <td class="tg-left">14</td><td class="tg-right">12</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Intelligence</h1></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Wisdom</h1></td><td class="tg-left">10</td><td class="tg-right">15</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Charisma</h1></td></tr></table></div><div class="charav" style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/mNQ1bXs/bringmeasonghatch.png)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="signature">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">paxton</li><div class="bpyand">&&</div>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">songurseinth</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content current tab-1">
      <div class="charname" style="color:var(--pax);">Paxton</div>
      <div class="charblock"><div class="charinfo">liaison-turned-weyrling<br>23 turns, female<br>curious, charismatic<br>hardworking, professional</div></div><div class="charstats"><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Strength</h1></th><th class="tg-left">8</th><th class="tg-right">13</th><th class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Dexterity</h1></th></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Constitution</h1></td> <td class="tg-left">14</td><td class="tg-right">12</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Intelligence</h1></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Wisdom</h1></td><td class="tg-left">10</td><td class="tg-right">15</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--pax);"><h1>Charisma</h1></td></tr></table></div><div class="charav" style="background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/67198afb06c5f06e21d99f13b8b80614/tumblr_pi3a8czLo71xfq869o1_500.gif)">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content tab-2">
      <div class="charname" style="color:var(--song);">Songurseinth</div>
      <div class="charblock"><div class="charinfo">liaison-turned-weyrling<br>23 turns, female<br>curious, charismatic<br>hardworking, professional</div></div><div class="charstats"><table class="tg"><tr><th class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Strength</h1></th><th class="tg-left">8</th><th class="tg-right">13</th><th class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Dexterity</h1></th></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Constitution</h1></td> <td class="tg-left">14</td><td class="tg-right">12</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Intelligence</h1></td></tr><tr><td class="tg-left" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Wisdom</h1></td><td class="tg-left">10</td><td class="tg-right">15</td><td class="tg-right" style="color:var(--song);"><h1>Charisma</h1></td></tr></table></div><div class="charav" style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/mNQ1bXs/bringmeasonghatch.png)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```